# JAVA return unexpected boolean result from method

Tags: java

Why the following method always return **false** for the below value.
Do I confuse with somethings??

```
public boolean isTwoWay(Detail detail) {
    return (detail.isExchange && detail.isTwoWay && !detail.isIVR);
}
```

which data contain following

```
detail.isExchange =  true;
detail.isTwoWay = true;
detail.isIVR = false;
```

but it return **false** instead of **true**

Comment: Are those boolean variables static? Your initialization of the form `Detail.isExchange = true;` implies they are static (unless it's a typo).

Comment: What do the is* methods look like?

Comment: Are the booleans being set elsewhere?

Comment: Your code is. . . confusing. `Detail.isExchange` is apparently being set as a static variable in the `Detail` class. And then you are calling `detail.isExchange()` as a method? Perhaps show a bit more code here.

Comment: Add those methods `isExchange()`, etc here too.

Comment: okay sorry will edit question first

Comment: `detail.isTwoWay`  != `detail.isTwoWat`

Comment: @FranMontero detail.isTwoWay wrong typo

Comment: The logic is correct so the values must not be what you think they are. Try stopping on this line with a debugger and making sure `detail` has the state you expect. Or print the values if you can't use a debugger.

Comment: @sprinter thankyou for confirm that logic is correct. will try to check value

Comment: print all 3 variables before returning from that method to verify whether those variables contain correct values

Comment: Thank you man, as you guy said value is wrong there is a place modify this value before it enter this method (fail becoz put business logic in getter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way the method will return false is if one of your assumptions is wrong:

> ```
> detail.isExchange =  true;
> detail.isTwoWat = true;
> detail.isIVR = false;
> ```

Rest assured, this kind of oversight happens to programmers all the time, including the best of us.

Put a breakpoint where you receive false instead of your expected true, and verify your assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with that and its print true always.

```
boolean isExchange =  true;
boolean isTwoWay = true;
boolean isIVR = false;

System.out.println(isExchange && isTwoWay && !isIVR);
```